# Apache not assigning correct MIME type for .manifest HTML5 offline file

Tags: html, xampp, web-applications, html5-appcache

I'm running XAMPP apache web server and developing an HTML5 project and the .manifest file is not being 'assigned' the correct MIME type by the web server.

If a user accesses my HTML5 web app and tries to use it offline it will fail because my web server is not assigning the correct MIME type for my app's .manifest file.

Here is my question:  is there a configuration I need to set in my Apache web server so that the "text/cache-manifest" MIME type is assigned?

I have *already* tried this change in my .htaccess file found in the root of my web server, c:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess -- this is the entire .htaccess file's contents in the root of my web server at c:/xampp/htdocs, and I added the last 2 lines here, and neither my .manifest file nor (if I change it) a file with the extension .appcache is going to be accessed by a visitor to my web app, because the MIME type is still not being assigned by my web server to the correct type of "text/cache-manifest":

```
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "FORBIDDEN AREA"
 AuthUserfile "../htdocs/forbidden/.htpasswd"
 Require valid-user

 AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
 AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

Is there something else in my XAMPP web server I need to set so that the .manifest or .appcache file gets assigned the correct "text/cache-manifest" MIME type?

Answer (score 2):

To serve appcache mime-type in Apache "and Xampp is apache inside", add this line to your config file: mime.types

```
text/cache-manifest             appcache
```

into your file mime.types located

```
xampp\apache\conf\mime.types
```

Comment: FYI: I just checked the current XAMPP version. This seems to configured correctly and enabled by default now.